# URL redirecting in localhost

Tags: php, apache

I am using a simple htaccess file to rewrite urls of my project. I rewrite the whole url in a get variable, then use php to parse it.

My problem is when I try to send redirect headers, I can't seem to get it right.

For example, say I am viewing the page

```
localhost/myProject/home
```

With the header

```
header('Location: login');
```

it redirects to

```
localhost/myProject/home/login
```

When I try

```
 header('Location: /login');
```

it takes me to

```
localhost/login
```

which does not exist and I get a 404 error.

So far the only way I have found to work is when I do

```
header('Location: http://localhost/myProject/login');
```

but I don't think that is a good option because when my site goes live I will have to change every single header.

Is there a better way to do it?

My .htacces file is:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /myProject/

#Make sure it's not an actual file 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#Make sure its not a directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

#Rewrite the request to index.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?get=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this : Use base url variable for that.Define that variable global or in config file.You have to only change that variable one time:

```
$base_url = "http://google.com"; or define('base_url', 'http://google.com');
```

Comment: so I should then change my header to header("Location: ".base_url."/login"); ?